# Powershell regex broken

Tags: regex, powershell

There is some string (its always should be . at the end)

```
$A = 'Send email to: mail@domain.com.'
```

Also there is code that as i understand should delete everything but email

```
(([regex]'Send email to:(.*?)\.').Match($A).Value -replace "Send email to: |\.") -replace ";$"
```

Problem is that code broken and it make

```
mail@domain
```

instead of

```
mail@domain.com
```

how can it be fixed and what is the meaning of ";$" ?

Comment: Perhaps be more specific and use the @ in the match and match the last dot `Send email to: ([^@\s]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@.]+)\.`  https://regex101.com/r/szg90u/1 In the replacement use the first capturing group `$1`

Comment: You can use `$` as the anchor for the end of the line: `'Send email to:(.*?)\.$'`. It forces the non-greedy `?` to take characters past the non-ultimate dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about deleting what you don't want? `$` means the end of the line.  `.` means any character, so it needs escaping with a `\`.  No second argument to -replace implies replacing it with $null, or deleting it.  You can put multiple -replace operators together.  Check out https://regex101.com to try out regex patterns.

```
$A -replace 'Send email to: ' -replace '\.$'

mail@domain.com
```

Or with the `|` or symbol:

```
$A -replace 'Send email to: |\.$'

mail@domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You might make the match a bit more specific by capturing an email like format in the group and match the trailing dot.

In the replacement use group 1 `$1`

```
\bSend email to: ([^@\s]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@.]+)\.
```

- `\bSend email to:`  Match literally preceded with a word boundary
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^@\s]+` Match 1+ times any char except @ or a whitespace char
  - `@[^\s@]+` Match the `@` followed by same as previous pattern
  - `\.[^\s@.]+` Match the `.` followed by same as previous pattern
- `)\.` Close group and match a dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bWL2MP/1) | [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8VRwVZBPTg1L0UhNTcxM0ehJN9KAcRwSMkHUnl6yfm5eupcQGW6RakFOYnJqRiqNaLjHGKKY7UdouNiih1itWP0wAy9WG3NGD11HXUVQ/X//wE)

For example

```
$A = 'Send email to: mail@domain.com.'
$A -replace 'Send email to: ([^@\s]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@.]+)\.','$1'
```

Output

```
mail@domain.com
```